# Llamar a métodos de la clase maestra desde otra clase instanciada dentro de esta en PHP

Tags: php, herencia, diseño-de-clases, instancias

Tengo una clase maestra (que llamo core), que tiene instanciadas dentro otras 30 clases, por ejemplo para gestión de usuarios o para la base de datos, simplificando mucho, las clases se inician parecido a esto:

```
class core
{
    private function initClasses(array $listado_clases) {
        foreach ($listado_clases as $clase) {
            include "class_".${$clase}.".php";
            ${$clase} = new ${$clase}
        }
    }
}
```

También tengo un método __call que permite llamar directamente a los métodos de las otras clases, por ejemplo para la clase usuarios podría llamar un método de estas dos formas:

```
$core->usuarios->user_info();
$core->user_info();
```

Todo esto funciona bien, el problema surge cuando necesito llamar desde una de estas clases instanciadas a un método dentro de la clase core o de otra de las clases instanciadas, por ejemplo, si quiero llamar a un método de la clase **db** desde la clase de **usuarios**, en la clase core existiría este método puesto que la clase db está instanciada dentro:

```
$this->db->query();
```

Pero si trato de llamar a esta clase desde dentro de la clase usuarios, no existe.

He encontrado una solución que funciona, que es pasar toda la clase core a las otras clases instanciadas añadiendo $this como parámetro al iniciarla y creando un wrapper dentro de la otra clase. Esto genera una recursión (de hecho al ver el objeto aparece **RECURSION**), porque inserto la propia clase dentro de si misma, pero curiosamente no parece producir problemas, es algo similar a esto:

```
    class core
    {
        private function initClasses(array $listado_clases) {
            foreach ($listado_clases as $clase) {
                include "class_".${$clase}.".php";
                ${$clase} = new ${$clase}($this)
            }
        }
    }
```

En la clase instanciada, por ejemplo usuarios, está hecho así:

```
class usuarios
{
    public function __construct($core)
    {
        $this->core = $core;
    }

    public function muestraUsuario($id)
    {
        return $this->core->db->query(SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = $id);
    }
}
```

De esta forma puedo llamar dentro de esta clase a métodos que están instanciados dentro de core.

¿Existe una forma más correcta de hacer esto?

Tengo mucho código usando esta clase, así que necesito que se puedan seguir llamando a todos los métodos como está ahora, ya que en este momento todos los métodos se llaman desde la clase core sin importar en cual están realmente, por ejemplo:

```
$core->db->query();
$core->usuarios->user_info();
```

Gracias por cualquier ayuda o comentario.

Comment: El problema se da porque no estas utilizando POO con herencias. Ninguna de tus clases extiende otra, por lo cual no heredan ningún método. Si tus clases van a requerir `core` podrían extenderla o asumir su existencia y usarla de manera global (_al bastante feo, pero..._)

Comment: Lo he probado, pero me pierde los objetos: 
class db extends core {
   public function test() { echo $this->coreObject;}
}

$core->db->test(); devuelve null.
Así que fallan casi todas los métodos si los llamo desde la clase extendida porque no están los objetos definidos.

Comment: Por estos días no es muy popular, pero puede que lo que estes necesitando es [un Singleton](https://refactoring.guru/es/design-patterns/singleton/php/example#example-1)